# Wrong position of rightBarButtonItem in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to put the `view` of a `UINavigationController` into another view controller's `view`. The problem is that the right bar button is misplaced on iOS 10. On iOS 8 and 9 it looks good.

iOS 8 and 9:

[image]

iOS 10:

[image]

Here's the code how i add the navigation controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let viewController = MyViewController()
    navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    addChildViewController(navController)
    navController.view.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(navController.view)
    navController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

In MyViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        barButtonSystemItem: .done,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(doneButtonPressed)
    )
}
```

Also there are no clipped views (except the button itself). See snapshot of IB Debug View Hierachy:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by forwarding the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` events to the navigation controller's root view controller.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navController.viewControllers.first?.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    navController.viewControllers.first?.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're adding the subviews in the ViewDidLoad and not viewDidAppear, try changing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let viewController = MyViewController()
    navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
    addChildViewController(navController)
    navController.view.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(navController.view)
    navController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

to this:

```
    let viewController = MyViewController()

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()
     if(self.childViewControllers.contains(viewController) != true){
        navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        navController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        addChildViewController(navController)
        navController.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(navController.view)
        navController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

      }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that's the right approach, since `viewDidAppear` can be called multiple times in the lifecycle and `viewDidLoad` only once.

Comment: Yes, that's a different issue, I will edit my code accordingly :-)

Comment: This is not very clean. I try to prevent one time functionality in functions that get called multiple times. I solved my problem differently. But with your help i actually figured out, that the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` event are not called at all. Thank you for that!